# div move up and down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want a div content items interchange. I searched google and found this url: http://jsfiddle.net/RrbzM/4/ In this fiddle, every number have up and down. By clicking this link the content will interchange. But I do not want one more up and down link.

My webpage have a yellow highlight color. I have Up and Down buttons. By clicking this button, highlight yellow section moves to up [the values also.]

Please refer the following location:
http://jsfiddle.net/XKwvP/

Comment: Questions usually have a `?`, and not a list of demands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i written a sample code you can refer this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DKXNw/

Answer (score 1):

Why not use sortable? JqueryUI pretty solid and easy to use.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#default
And if you need touch functionality, here is an add on that fixes it. 
http://furf.com/exp/touch-punch/sortable.html